# I can not use the import command not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, terminal, debian

i need to import csv for a python program on debian but whenever i try the command `import csv` i get the error `bash: import: command not found`

I have python 3.9 installed so i'm lost as to what to do. I have not found any usefull answers to my question anywhere.